# Why won't my icon show up as full size on the new Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a published extension in the Chrome Web Store. Last night, the web store got an updated look, and now my icon appears really small, inside of a jigsaw puzzle piece. I followed the [instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest#icons), and uploaded a 128, 48, and 16. All three image files are PNG. My extension is the only one I have seen that is displaying in this way. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I guess this is by design, but it seems like a poor choice :-p

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a feature of the store, not a problem with your listing.

All extensions now show their icon inside of a jigsaw puzzle piece;
"apps" are free of it.

Comment: I see that that is the case now, but when I made my post mine was one of the only extensions with the puzzle piece. Either way, seems more like a bug than a feature.