# Why does my icon show up inside jigsaw puzzle on Chrome Web Store?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have followed the guideline to provide a 128x128 icon with blank 16 pixels padding. Why cannot I display my icon with full size as other extensions?

Here is how my extension icon looks at top-left corner:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-mappingbird/ipjijcfmgfehpiiigjgjdgkldeligkfo?hl=en-US

Here is how Wunderlist icon looks:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wunderlist-to-do-and-task/fjliknjliaohjgjajlgolhijphojjdkc?hl=en-US

Comment: Your icon isn't showing up properly in which part? Could you provide the screenshot of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my icon show up as full size on the new Chrome Web Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890713/why-wont-my-icon-show-up-as-full-size-on-the-new-chrome-web-store)

Comment: Here is how my extension icon looks at top-left corner: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-mappingbird/ipjijcfmgfehpiiigjgjdgkldeligkfo?hl=en-US)
Here is how Wunderlist icon looks: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wunderlist-to-do-and-task/fjliknjliaohjgjajlgolhijphojjdkc?hl=en-US)

Comment: It's because Wunderlist is an app rather than an extension. It seems to be the intend behavior only for extensions in Chrome web store now.

Comment: Thank you gui47. Finally, I know what happened. :)